Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Installer unable to press next and proceed with the installation
I want to install Ubuntu on my iMac in triple boot setup.
So I have macOS and Windows setup on the /dev/sda1 /boot/efi partition.
If I install Ubuntu on this device I loose my Windows boot option.
Now I want to install the Ubuntu bootloader on another partition.
I created a 1GB VFAT partition on /dev/sda7 and mounted it on /boot/efi. But now the installer won't allow me to proceed, because I can't press the "next" button.
On Parrot OS and Debian I am able to do this in a similar way and it does allow me to install. So I guess for Ubuntu it should also be possible.
This is the step I'm stuck at:

Can you help me to resolve this?

Not quite sure, but it seems that sda6+7 do not exist. These partitions need to have unoccupied space

How would you lose your Windows boot option if you use the existing EFI partition sda1 (and you don't format it of course)? If there's room, Ubuntu just gets files in another directory, and probably replacing the device fallback bootloader EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi.  Maybe the installer is refusing to create a second EFI partition, but I didn't think it was that smart. One EFI partition per device is what the spec says.

@kanehekili - for as far as I know the partitions do exist because they were previously used by Parrot OS. Now they are marked as to be formatted. I have clicked on the sda to have it high lighted but still I can't press next.

@ubfan1 I think it has something to do with the partition tables that get overwritten. Since the Windows installation with Bootcamp doesn't create a Microsoft folder in the EFI partition. I guess the partition table will be rewritten with the Linux install and that that is where it loses the Windows boot info.

@ubfan1 I am aware of these partition tables:
Current GPT partition table
Current MBR partition table
But creating a separate Linux EFI partition works.
That way it leaves the bootloader for Windows Bootcamp intact.
With Parrot OS and Debian I have already been able to achieve a working solution. Now I want to be able to do it with Ubuntu and I get stuck in the screen provided in the screenshot being unable to press next.

Did you ensure that only one EFI partition has the "boot,esp" flags?  Use gparted to see/fix.

Finally I made it happen. With the previous information I was more focussed on getting all the OSes on the EFI pratition. Thanks @ubfan1 Now I found this tutorial online that explains how to use the bcdboot utility of Windows to make it to write the required boot files to the EFI partition. I had tried it before with other manuals but failed, with this one I managed to do it. See: [link] ( https://medium.com/macoclock/how-to-install-windows-10-on-an-external-drive-on-a-mac-f02b1beda8c8) As a note I just used my internal drive instead of the external as is describes.

Now I could just do a normal Ubuntu installation following the installer. And my iMac triple boots with rEFInd.

You can write your own answer, and accept it after a bit, helping others and gaining some reputation points in the process.

I managed to get the Microsoft EFI boot files on the EFI partition.
Boot into the Windows installer
On the first screen press SHIFT + F10
# diskpart
# list disk
# select disk 0
# list part
Look for the Windows partition

# select part 3
# assign letter=W
# format quick fs=NTFS
# list volume
Look for the EFI volume

# select volume 2
# assign letter=Z
# exit

# D:
Goto the USB installer of Windows
# cd D:\sources
# dir install*
The file install.esd exists

# dism /Get-WimInfo /WimFile:D:\Sources\install.esd
Select the Index of the version of Windows you want

# dism /Apply-image /ImageFile:D:\Sources\install.esd /index:6 /ApplyDir:W:\
# bcdboot W:\Windows /l en-us /s Z: /f UEFI
Shutdown your computer and remove the USB installer
Now we have the Microsoft EFI boot files in the EFI partition in its designated folder

Follow the normal procedure of installing Windows
And create a USB rEFIt boot disk
# hdiutil convert /path/to/refit-0.14.cdr -format UDRW -o /path/to/refit-0.14.img
# diskutil list
# diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk2
# sudo dd if=/path/to/refit-0.14.img.dmg of=/dev/rdisk2 bs=1m
# diskutil eject /dev/disk2

Any questions? Let me know!
